# If string contains x do y in R

Tags: r, string

So I'm having a data frame with an ID section that looks something like this

```
ID
Anna1
Anna1
Anton2
Anton2
```

I want to create a new variable that contains "1" if there's a 1 in the ID and 2 if there's a "2" in the variable.

So far I've come up with this

```
Fixations$test <- (ifelse(Fixations$ID %in% 1  ,"1", 
                              ifelse(Fixations$ID  %in% 2, "2", NA)))
```

Obviously, it doesn't work because my reference to the string is wrong. Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `grepl`:

```
ifelse(grepl("1", Fixations$ID), "1", 
ifelse(grepl("2", Fixations$ID), "2", NA))
```

The last parameter defines the value to assign when neither "1" or "2" occurs.

Comment: If it's really only a decision between `1` and `2`, even `2 - grepl("1", Fixations$ID)` would do the trick.

Comment: Edited answer for the problem of multiple decisions.

Answer (score 2):

We could use `extract_numeric` from `tidyr` package:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    mutate(test = extract_numeric(ID))
```

Output:

```
      ID test
1  Anna1    1
2  Anna1    1
3 Anton2    2
4 Anton2    2
```

Comment: Hi @tarjae, If I want to extract the number on the same `id` column, how should I approach then?

Comment: @Roy I do not understand exactly. Maybe you want `group_by` and then extract or use `distinct()`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
Fixations %>% 
    mutate(test = case_when(str_detect(ID, '1$')~ 1,
       str_detect(ID, '2$') ~ 2))
      ID test
1  Anna1    1
2  Anna1    1
3 Anton2    2
4 Anton2    2
```

---

Another option is `parse_number`

```
readr::parse_number(Fixations$ID)
[1] 1 1 2 2
```

#### data

```
Fixations <- structure(list(ID = c("Anna1", "Anna1", "Anton2", 
    "Anton2")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about extracting the string that you want ?

This will extract the number from `ID` column.

```
stringr::str_extract(df$ID, '\\d+')
#[1] "1" "1" "2" "2"
```

If you are interested only in 1 and 2 values and make other numbers as `NA` you can also specify such pattern in regex.

```
stringr::str_extract(df$ID, '(1|2)$')
```